# Replace .set() of immutableJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reducers

i've to clean up all my project from immutableJS, now my question is how can I replace

```
  return state.set('loaded', true);
```

if i try to

```
state.loaded = true
```

ESlint show me this error [Disallow Reassignment of Function Parameters (no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)

the complete code is this

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import { APP_READY } from '../actions/appActions';
import { USER_LOGOUT } from '../actions/logoutActions';

const initialState = Map({
  loaded: false,
});

const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case APP_READY:
      return state.set('loaded', true);
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return state.set('loaded', true);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default appReducer;
```

**What's the best way to replace .set of Immutable js ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case APP_READY:
     return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true
     };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

While you might get rid of ImmutableJS your resolver still must not mutate the state. You must return a new object. This can either be done in ES6 via `{ ...state, loading: true }` or with `Object.assign({}, state, { loaded: true })` if you are using an older version of EcmaScript.